# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 gradle how to run the java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

how can I run my gradle project? Its a GUI application. I just want to run it so I can test it. Created a gradle project, copied my src file in and marked it as a source file (blue file). Now when I click run, the project runs all the gradle tasks but my application does not start. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
group '1'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Main'
version = '1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {

    baseName = 'JavaWinApp'
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from { configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) } }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'JavaWinApp'
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': version
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:6.0.5'
}
```

Can you see anything blatantly obvious that I should change or can you give me any pointers?

Please let me know if you require any other information and I will happily supply it. I am an utter noob with this. My only exposure to gradle is through Android Studio, there all just runs fine. Looks like I'm missing something obvious, but cannot seem to find it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your Main class have a package name? I would expect your class name in `'Main-Class': 'Main'` to be fully qualified, i.e. `com.stackoverflow.Main`. That said: I don't think IntelliJ's run configuration is likely to enter your code using the default entry point of the jar, so that may not make a difference.

Comment: Given that you click "Run": have you checked what your Run Configuration actually purports to do? It may just be a Run Configuration which _builds_ a jar (and outputs it to the build folder without executing it). You need to use the `Java Application` Run Configuration if you want to actually _execute_ the Java program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradle application plugin should add a `run` task to your build, that will start your application. To execute this task you will need to create a run configuration in IntelliJ for this task. See [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-gradle-tasks-in-gradle-tool-window.html) on how to create a gradle run/debug configuration.